# Cumulative dot product with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have an ndarray A, populated with N squared DxD matrices (shape (N,D,D)).
I want to transform it into an ndarray B of the same shape, where B[0]=A[0] and for every i>0, B[i] = np.dot(B[i-1], A[i]).
While a basic implementation is obvious, I wondered whether this operation has a faster implementation than a for loop.

Let me, For example, describe another way to perform the calculation:

1. B[0...N/2] = compute for A[0]...A[N/2 - 1] the basic way
2. B[N/2...N] = compute for A[N/2]...A[N] the basic way
3. return np.concatenate((B[0...N/2 - 1], np.dot(B[N/2 - 1], B[N/2...N])]

The emphasis is that 1 and 2 can be done in parallel and 3 is a vectorized operation - and that this split can be further applied for each half on the array as needed.
This makes me wonder if a better option than the basic for loop exists (e.g whether what I'm suggesting is implemented/is an actual improvement, or whether another option is preferrable).

Many thanks,

Yiftach

**Edit:** code for most basic implementation, for benchmarking:

```
import numpy as np

def cumdot(A):
    B = np.empty(A.shape)
    B[0] = A[0]
    for i in range(1, A.shape[0]):  
        B[i] = B[i - 1] @ A[i]
    return B
```

**Edit2:** It seems like in numpy, all ufuncs support a .accumulate() (which is exactly what I'm trying to do), and matmul (which behaves like a dot product), is a *generalized* ufunc. That means matmul is not a function from two scalars to one, but from two matrices to a matrix, and therefore while the function accumulate exist, calling it will raise an exception stating that accumulate is not callable on ufuncs that have a signature. If this can be made to work despite the signature thing, I'd also love to know.

Comment: Share your loop-based implementation? Asking because  any vectorized solution could be referred against it for verification. Also, please readup on [`mcve`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: There is a `np.linalg.multidot`, but that only returns the last of the series, not the intermediate steps.  And it deviates from the standard loop only if some the arrays differ significantly in size.  Then you may gain performance by first performing the 'dots' that reduce dimensions fastest.  SInce all your `A` are the same size the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Something like `np.moveaxis(np.dot(B[:-1, ...], A[1:, ...]), 2, 1)[np.arange(A.shape[0] - 1), np.arange(B.shape[0] - 1), ...]`, but without having to extract the diagonal would probably work.

Comment: I'm playing with getting `np.einsum('hij,hjk->hik', B[:-1, ...], A[1:, ...])` to work by rearranging the dimensions...

Comment: @hpaulj. Is there some way to turn off buffering so something like `np.matmul(B[:-1, ...], A[1:, ...], out=B[1:, ...])` could work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a fully vectorized way to do this with just numpy functions (but I'd be happy to be proven wrong!).

You can hide the loop by using `itertools.accumulate` to generate the cumulative products.  Here's an example.  To create `A`, I'll use `N` random orthogonal matrices, generated using `scipy.stats.ortho_group`, to ensure that the products remain bounded.

The first few lines here create `A`, with shape (1000, 4, 4).

```
In [101]: from scipy.stats import ortho_group

In [102]: N = 1000

In [103]: D = 4

In [104]: A = ortho_group.rvs(D, size=N)
```

Compute the cumulative products with `itertools.accumulate`, and put the result in a numpy array.

```
In [105]: from itertools import accumulate

In [106]: B = np.array(list(accumulate(A, np.matmul)))
```

Verify that we get the same result from `cumdot(A)`.

```
In [107]: def cumdot(A): 
     ...:     B = np.empty(A.shape) 
     ...:     B[0] = A[0] 
     ...:     for i in range(1, A.shape[0]):   
     ...:         B[i] = B[i - 1] @ A[i] 
     ...:     return B 
     ...:                                                                                         

In [108]: B0 = cumdot(A)                                                                          

In [109]: (B == B0).all()                                                                         
Out[109]: True
```

Check the performance.  It turns out the using `itertools.accumulate` is slightly faster.

```
In [110]: %timeit B0 = cumdot(A)
2.89 ms ± 31.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [111]: %timeit B = np.array(list(accumulate(A, np.matmul)))
2.44 ms ± 33.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```